# No Funciona JavaScript en el Formulario

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo dos botones dentro del formulario,uno llama a una función javascript para realizar una operaciones, y funciona perfectamente, pero al añadir el form action con su correspondiente botón para realizar el submit, javascript ya no funciona.

El formulario se envía correctamente.
Si quito el form action, se ejecuta correctamente javascript.

¿Alguien podría decirme cual es el problema?
Gracias

```js
 <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
                                <script>
 
 function pedido() {
 .........................
}
</script>
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <form action="añadir pedido.php" method="POST"> 
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3 " onclick="pedido();"><span></span>Confirmar Producto</button>
 <h3 class="mb-4 billing-heading">Detalles del Envío</h3>
            <div class="row align-items-end">
             <div class="col-md-6">
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="firstname">Nombre</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="nombre">
                 </div>
               </div>
                </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lastname">Apellidos</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="apellidos">
                 </div>
                </div>
                <button name="confirmar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3"><span></span>Confirmar Pedido</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: En el `<button type="submit">` para confirmar el pedido haces algun insert en la BD? , porque lo que hace es refrescar la página y re-direccionar a la página dónde le indiques el `action` por eso pasa por alto el JS, si requieres insertar pero que no refresque la página puedes hacerlo por AJAX y agregar un `event.preventDefault();` para que no haga el submit.

Comment: La función pedido guarda el pedido, que después es enviado en el form. Y el action llama al .php que realiza el insert en la bdd.Tengo otros formularios de la misma manera y si que funciona javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Un form común HTML para ser enviado tiene que ser mas o menos así:

```
<form action="POST">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>
```

Si faltara `action` no queda otra que hacer un ajax, si falta `type="submit"` lo puedes hacer con js haciendo `.submit()` y si tienes un form común como el anterior y quieres validarlo antes de enviarlo debes usar `preventDefault()`, ejemṕlo:

```js
$('#enviar').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  
  //validamos
  if (!$("#valor").val()) {
    alert("no envies vacio!");
  } else {
    $("#formulario").submit();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario" action="POST">
  <input id="valor" type="text">
  <button id="enviar" type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>
```